# Service worker implementation architecture?

Tags: web-applications, service-worker

I have to implement a service worker for my web site, which is a collection of pages with angularjs and non angularjs pages. Every angularjs page is an SPA with on page routing. So Please tell me if I have to write a single service worker for all the pages or I can write a separate service worker for every page?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, creating a single, top-level service worker scoped to `'/'` should be sufficient. Inside that service worker's `fetch` event handler, you can examine the request's URL and [mode](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-mode) (e.g. `'navigate'`) and take appropriate action depend on what subpage is being accessed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44646005/using-service-worker-in-angularjs Any help ?