# Using service worker in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, firefox, service-worker

How we can get event fired in service worker in our angularjs app.

Here is sample code which is working and showing notification in chrome/firefox

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
console.log('[Service Worker] Push Received.');
// console.log(`[Service Worker] Push had this data: "${event.data.text()}"`);

console.log(event.data);
console.log(event.data.json());
console.log(typeof (event.data.json()));
console.log(event);

window.dispatchEvent( new Event('dataisthere') );

const title = 'YummZ';
const options = {
    body: 'Message Received \n ' + event.data.json().message,
    icon: 'images/icon.png',
    // badge: 'images/badge.png',
    data : event.data.json()
};

event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, options));
});
```

I tried to dispatch a window event but i got error **window is undefined**

when service worker get push notification, i need to notify my angular app to perform action.

**NOTE: NEW TO SERVICE WORKER**

Comment: @jeff-posnick Any idea?

Comment: hi, did u find a solution ? pls post back the solution if u have found. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have a read on [this](http://craig-russell.co.uk/2016/01/29/service-worker-messaging.html).  Havent tested it yet but I think the general idea for the solution you are looking for is there.  The title says **How to Send Messages Between Service Workers and Clients,** so if you manage to bridge that gap, you can pretty much tell your service worker to do whatever you want.

Comment: This 'http://craig-russell.co.uk/2016/01/29/service-worker-messaging.html#.XFaZuk5fjeM' is for Service workers in Javascript... 

the ? question ? is actually about service worker event handling in Angular JS... Angular 1.x ...